# After perfoming tune up to my jetta 2.0

Tags: vw, exhaust, sparkplugs, jetta, water-leak

After performing tune up to the car due to misfiring replacing
spark pugs 
new wires
new gas filter
When finished and started the car a lot of water came out of the exhaust like never saw it before.

why this happened?
is this Normal?

Comment: More information [here](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/11316/4152), but not  necessarily an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the exhaust does not smell sweet, you should be in good shape. With the misfire, you could have been dumping excess amounts of unburnt fuel, which could account for the water. If the engine is now running good and you don't continually see excessive amounts of water sloshing out, the is probably nothing to worry about. If you haven't done so already, run the vehicle long enough to ensure the exhaust system gets completely up to operating temperature for a good period of time ... like about 30 minutes of highway driving. This will ensure any residual water in the system has be evaporated out.