# Water vapor, and dripping from tailpipe, no fluid loss

Tags: engine

Even after warmed up, the tailpipe has a small but steady amount of water vapor. The weather is cold, but the car. has been warmed up.  There is no loss of coolant from overflow tank or rad. Steam and drops are clear and have no smell. When I swipe my finger on the inside of.the pipe I get soot/water. Just got this car and apparently it has been doing this for years.

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/34830/10976

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly normal operation. One of the byproducts of combustion is water or water vapor and when it is cold outside the vapor condenses. However I wouldn't drink that water because it has all kinds of nasty stuff dissolved  into it most of which are poisonous. Apart from how you engine performs there is nothing to worry about.