# BMW engine cooling issue

Tags: cooling-system, bmw, overheating

So I have 316i E92 (N43), it was super fine with a minor hose leaking issue but that create more issues later and ended up replacing the radiator, water pump, and thermostat.
recently when I drive normally nothing happens, but when I pushed into power mode (around 4K RPM) and drive it for a distance it shows overheating warning (no red warning, only an orange warning to suggest driving slowly until the engine cooldown), and when I check I found water around the water bottle.

So I did replace the thermostat again + the water temp sensor. no more overheating warning but again water around the bottle (with an almost empty bottle). but when we check with OBD the car temperature is always at 81°C while the hoses are extremely hot!!!.

what's the possible issue here?

*PS: I don't know if related, but in the cold start when I accelerate there is some water coming out from the exhaust.*

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm about 99% positive the water coming out of the exhaust right after start up is *very normal*. [Check out this answer for why.](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/11316/4152)

Comment: First of all the water during cold start is condensation, not cooling system fluid.
Second, the standard working temperature is 90ºC, so 81 is good enough, the hoses at >70ºC are extremely hot. 
Finally to avoid the expansion bottle leaks you can check the o-ring or a possible cross-threaded cup