# Head gasket leak repair

Tags: head-gasket

I notice steam coming from tail pipe i told my friend and he said it was a head gasket so I bought blue devil head gasket repair I added blue devil through the upper hose of radiator which goes through thermostat but I forgot to put heater on while the 50minute procedure was gone on will blue devil still work

Comment: Had you been loosing water from the cooling system?

Comment: It is normal for steam to come from the exhaust pipe, since water is one of the products of combustion. It is more noticeable when the exhaust system is cold, or on a cold day (as with animal exhalation).

Comment: [This answer](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/11316/4152) I wrote previously might be of some help in understanding what @WeatherVane is trying to describe.